# Installing Python 3.10 on Anaconda (Win 11)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I have a fresh install of Anaconda 2022.10 on Windows 11. I'm using the following command to install a fresh environment with Python 3.10 (I've used the exact same command few weeks ago on my Linux box and it worked):

```
conda create --name tf anaconda python=3.10
```

Strangely, it doesn't seem to work in Windows. Here is the error message:

```
(base) C:\Users\s\Documents>conda create --name tf anaconda python=3.10
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package python conflicts for:
python=3.10
anaconda -> python[version='2.7.13|2.7.14|2.7.14|2.7.15|2.7.15|2.7.16|3.6.10|3.6.10|3.7.10|3.7.11|3.7.13|3.8.13|3.9.13|3.9.12|3.9.7|3.8.12|3.8.8|3.9.4|3.7.9|3.8.5|3.7.7|3.8.3|3.8.1|3.7.6|3.6.9|3.7.4|3.6.8|3.7.3|3.7.3|3.6.7|3.7.1|3.7.0|3.6.6|3.6.5|3.5.5|3.6.4|3.5.4|3.6.3|3.5.4|3.6.2|3.5.4|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0',build='hd3c4935_11|h6679aeb_11|hb034564_12|h59f5a59_20|hdec4e59_20|h8c3f1cb_23|h1357f44_23|h6538335_1|h0c2934d_0|hea74fb7_0|hea74fb7_0|hcb6e200_5|h9f7ef89_2|h8c8aaf0_0|h8c8aaf0_1|h9f7ef89_7|h5263a28_0|hcb6e200_0|h5fd99cc_8_cpython|h9f7ef89_2|h5fd99cc_1|h60c2a47_0|h6244533_0|h6244533_0|h6244533_0|h6244533_0|h6244533_0|h6244533_0|h6244533_0|h6244533_1|h6244533_1|hdbf39b2_5|h81c818b_4|he1778fa_2|h9f7ef89_0|h60c2a47_2|h5500b2f_0|h8c8aaf0_6|he216670_0|h0c2934d_2|h9e2ca53_1']
anaconda -> argon2-cffi==21.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python[version='!=3.0,!=3.1,!=3.2,!=3.3|>=3.5|>=3.6|>=3.7|>=3.6.1,<4.0|>=2.7|>=3|2.7|>=3.5|>=3.4|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.8|>=3.6,<4.0|>=3.6.1|3.6.*|3.5.*|3.4.*|2.7.*|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|>=3.3|>2.7|<4.0|>=3,<3.7|3.9.*|3.8.*|3.7.*']
```

Does anyone have any idea?

[Edit] This is what's in my Linux box. Maybe Python 3.10 was removed...

```
> conda list | grep -E 'anaconda|python'
# packages in environment at /home/steven/anaconda3/envs/tf:
anaconda                  2022.10                 py310_0  
anaconda-client           1.11.0          py310h06a4308_0  
anaconda-project          0.11.1          py310h06a4308_0  
ipython                   7.31.1          py310h06a4308_1  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
msgpack-python            1.0.3           py310hd09550d_0  
python                    3.10.4               h12debd9_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2          py310h06a4308_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1  
python-lsp-black          1.2.1           py310h06a4308_0  
python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-lsp-server         1.5.0           py310h06a4308_0  
python-on-whales          0.53.0                   pypi_0    pypi
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-snappy             0.6.0           py310h295c915_0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why this command worked on Linux.

When you go to the [Anaconda download page](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) there is still no Anaconda version based on Python 3.10 available. And this is in line with what the error message is telling you: The anaconda package requires Python<3.10.

However, most people don't care about the authored anaconda package, simply install Python 3.10 with

```
conda create --name tf python=3.10
```

and then add only the packages they actually need to the virtual environment. This is best practice anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added `conda list` from my Linux box to the question. Maybe 3.10 support was later removed...

Comment: Did my answer help to understand the error message or is something still unclear?

Comment: Thanks, it did clarify the error. I've manually installed all the packages I need.